# jpa criteria query add mark / text expression

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I've a long log of sql queries. I'm currently debugging some stuff and I need to find the sql queries for some criteria queries there.

I'd like to add something like `AND 'abc'='abc'` to my critera query in order to be able to find it in my query log more easily.

How would I write that in criteria query language?

Currently I have:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<String> cQuery = cb
        .createQuery( String.class )
        ;

Root<BackendArticle> ART = cQuery.from( BackendArticle.class );

Predicate pred = myPredicateBuilder.predicate( ART, cb );

pred = cb.and( pred, ??? ); //<- What to put here?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

may be help this code.

```
public List<yourclass> getdata(String abc)
{
Criteria criteria=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(yourclass.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("yourfiled",abc));
return Criteria.list();
}
```